# Error while navigating between components

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components

A component 1 redirect me to a component 2 and I'd like that in component 2, when I click on a return button, I'm redirected to component 1.

For navigate from component 2 to component 1, I use an event.

Component 2 :

```
<aura:registerEvent name="displayList" type="c.B_NavigateToList" />    
<button class="slds-button" onclick="{!c.goBack}">
    <lightning:icon iconName="action:back" size="small" class="icon" variant="bare"/>
</button>
```

The controller JS of component 2:

```
goBack : function(component, event, helper){
    console.log("retour vers la liste");
    var evt = $A.get("e.c:B_NavigateToList");
    evt.fire();
}
```

The event `B_NavigateToList` is a simple event with no parameter.

The main component, that display components 1 or 2, capturing the event :

```
<aura:handler event="c:B_NavigateToList" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

{!v.body}
```

Ant its controller method `doInit` :

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    $A.createComponent(
        "c:B_ContactComponent",
        {

        },
        function(newCmp){
            if (component.isValid()) {
                component.set("v.body", newCmp);
            }
        }
    );
},
```

So when I'm on the component 2 and I click on the return button, I got a javascript error :

> rerender threw an error in 'markup://aura:expression' [Cannot read property 'childNodes' of null]
>   Failing descriptor: {markup://aura:expression}

**EDIT**

I change the controller JS of component 2 like that :

```
goBack : function(component, event, helper){
    console.log("retour vers la liste");
    var evt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent");
    evt.setParams({
        componentDef : "c:B_ContactComponent",
    });
    evt.fire();
}
```

And now when I click the return button I don't get any error but nothing happen and I stay on component 2 instead of being redirected to component 1 (named "B_ContactComponent" ).

Comment: The {!c.goBack} action in your button, what does it call ? Where is it used ? Because i see that you do your call to another component in your doInit and that's not the way to implement the lightning component navigation if I'm not mistaken

Comment: Sorry I forgot to paste the code of controller JS, I updated my post with the `goBack` method

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Well I tried it in many ways, I ended up with an undefined event in the controller. It's still in beta...

So I went for the proven way, following this [guide](https://force-base.com/2016/01/04/how-to-navigate-from-one-component-to-another-in-lightning/).

The idea is that your main component has a {!v.body}, and registers to events handling the navigation. B_NavigateToList event of type **Application** for example.

```
<aura:handler event="c:B_NavigateToList" action="{!c.navigateToListAction}"/>
```

In the main component controller, you should implement this function

```
navigateToListAction: function(component,event,helper) {
  $A.createComponent(
     "c:B_ContactComponent",
     {
       "res" : event.getParam("result")
     },
     function(newCmp){
        if (component.isValid()) {
            component.set("v.body", newCmp);
        }
     }
  );
}
```

In your Component 2, consider implementing this function in the controller

```
goBack: function(component, event, helper) {
    var evt = $A.get("e.c:B_ContactComponent");
    evt.fire();
},
```

When the user clicks on the goBack in the component B, it fires the event B_NavigateToList, which will be caught by the main component. And rerender the body.

Hope this helps

---

Old solution not working (yet):

Why not use the (new/beta) feature force:navigateToComponent ?

Little example :

```
goBack: function(component, event, helper) {
    var evt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent");
    evt.setParams({
        componentDef : "c:Component1"
    });
    evt.fire();
}
```

It requires that the component is marked with access="global" or a component within the current namespace. And as it is a standard event of Lightning, it doesn't require the extras from using a custom event (no event creation, no handler, etc.).

[Source](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_navigateToComponent.htm)

But a [raised question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/163550/navigate-to-component-forcenavigatetocomponent) yesterday explained that this feature also overwrites the whole page (the lightning component is treated as the unique component to show). So if you use your lightning component in a page containing already other components, it's maybe not what you're looking for

Comment: I just tried that with my component, when I click the button there's no more error, but it don't redirect me to the first component...

Comment: @dou Did you make sure the component is marked as "global" ? The component 1 ? If there no typo in the call of the function ? I edited my answer to reflect more your use case. Check it out

Comment: yes I put access="global" in the component 1, and my method is exactly the same as yours, with a console.log inside it. And when I click the button I see the log (so the method is reached) but nothing else happens

Comment: @dou Edit The Question what you have tried now may be it helpful to resolve your issue

Comment: @vignesh I edited my post

Comment: @dou I edited once again my answer, I hope it'll help !

Comment: @SimonGovaert Thanks I tried your method but it is the same as I tried in first place, instead that in the main component I called the doInit method instead of `navigateToListAction`, but the event is the same, as the handler. And I stille got the error